# how to rewrite main domain to sub folder without changing url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, joomla2.5

I want to rewrite sub folder such as `http://example.com/new` to `http://example.com` with `.htaccess`
My site contents and files are in `/new` directory and I want the `/new` does not appears to users and user see the `example.com` without `/new` but load the files from `/new` directory.
I search very much but I couldn't find any things.
Are you have any solution to my problem?
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Very complicated what you want to do, is not more easy move all your actual /new to the root?